# How to replace massive if statement in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, if-statement

At moment I have massive of if statement like

```
    if ([dicIdentifer isEqualToString:CONF_KEY_CALLMETHOD]) {
    switch ([[settingDictionary objectForKey:PLIST_VALUE] intValue]) {
        case CASE_1:
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = SOME_TEXT_1
            break;
        case CASE_2:
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = SOME_TEXT_2
            break;
        case CASE_3:
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = SOME_TEXT_3
            break;
        case CASE_4:
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = SOME_TEXT_4
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
} else if ([dicIdentifer isEqualToString:CONF_KEY_HTTPMETHOD]) {
    switch ([[settingDictionary objectForKey:PLIST_VALUE] intValue]) {
        case CASE_1:
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = SOME_TEXT_1
            break;
        case CASE_2:
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = SOME_TEXT_2
            break;
        case CASE_3:
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = SOME_TEXT_3
            break;
        case CASE_4:
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = SOME_TEXT_4
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
} .....
```

I have ten more this type of "if" statement right now and that number is likely to increase. This works quite well but in terms of maintenance and efficiency I think it could be improved. I read the thread from [Ways to replace massive if statement with alternative construct in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069049/ways-to-replace-massive-if-statement-with-alternative-construct-in-objective-c). But it seems does not suit for my case. If some one would have suggestion about my case.

Thanks

Comment: You could always use a dictionary, with the key's being the `CASE` values, and the actual value being the `SOME_TEXT` variables.  Then instead of doing a switch, you could do a simple lookup and assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method in the question you linked to is perfectly suitable here. You just need two levels of dictionaries:

```
NSDictionary *dictionaryForCallMethod = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:SOME_TEXT_1, [NSNumber numberWithInt:CASE_1], SOME_TEXT_2, [NSNumber numberWithInt:CASE_2], SOME_TEXT_3, [NSNumber numberWithInt:CASE_3], SOME_TEXT_4, [NSNumber numberWithInt:CASE_4], nil];
NSDictionary *dictionaryForHTTPMethod = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:SOME_TEXT_1, [NSNumber numberWithInt:CASE_1], SOME_TEXT_2, [NSNumber numberWithInt:CASE_2], SOME_TEXT_3, [NSNumber numberWithInt:CASE_3], SOME_TEXT_4, [NSNumber numberWithInt:CASE_4], nil];
// create additional dictionaries for each branch of your if statement

NSDictionary *bigDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:dictionaryForCallMethod, CONF_KEY_CALLMETHOD, dictionaryForHTTPMethod, CONF_KEY_HTTPMETHOD, nil];
// put the other dictionaries in this dictionary as well

cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[bigDictionary objectForKey:dicIdentifier] objectForKey:PLIST_VALUE];
```